# What the need of redux for managing the state of an application?

Tags: javascript, angular

I know redux. I implemented it in an angular2 application for managing the state of the application. Can we replace it with singleton service in angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with a Singleton Service, with a shared Observable.
More on [**Shared Services**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) and [**ngrx**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx).

Comment: If I replace it with Singleton Service then what is the difference between them

Comment: the thing is that you need to manage all the connections yourselves, with redux you get state management at a higher abstract level where you can debug applications faster using ngrx suite and also , have complex object and slice and dice data